# Bring ProgressBar front, over the ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have a `RelativeLayout` in which i have a `ListView` and a `ProgressBar`. The `ListView` is below a bunch of other elements and the `ProgressBar` is centered in the screen.

Now, i use an `AsyncTask` and load data into the `ListView` and i want to show the `ProgressBar` while doing this.

When the list is empty, the `ProgressBar` is visible. But when the list has some elements already and when i try to load and refresh the data in the list, the `ProgressBar` is not being shown. This is possibly because the `ListView` is getting to the top (above the `ProgressBar`) when i set the adapter.

I tried using `progressbar.bringtofront()`, but no luck.

Here is my layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

...

<com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.DynamicListView
    android:id="@+id/favourites_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/refresh_button"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/refresh_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since i use a `.get()` in my `AsyncTask`, i update the `ProgressBar` in the `Activity` itself instead of updating it the traditional way in `AsyncTask`. Here is the code that i use to show and hide the `ProgressBar`.

```
//before i send the asynctask
refreshProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
refreshProgress.bringToFront();
ArrayList<String> response = task.execute(new String[]{url}).get();

...

//after parsing the response and setting the adapter for the listview
favoritesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
favoritesAdapter = new FavoritesAdapter(this, main_company, main_symbol, main_price, main_change, main_marketcap);
favoritesListView.setAdapter(favoritesAdapter);
refreshProgress.bringToFront();
refreshProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I want the `ProgressBar` to be shown on top of the `ListView` while using the `AsyncTask`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `DynamicListView` and `ProgressBar` in a `FrameLayout`. Since child views of a `FrameLayout` are drawn in a stack, the most recently added child (your `ProgressBar`) will appear on top.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem is with the `Asynctask`. When we use `.get()`, it becomes synchronous and waits on the main thread for the task to return. This prevented the `ProgressBar` from getting printed. I made into an asynchronous task (`Asynctask` => Asynchronous. Duh.) and it worked like magic!

Answer (score 0):

Or intead of ProgressBar you could use a ProgressDialog. You just have to publish data to the ProgressDialog through publishProgress() and onProgressUpdate() in the Asynctask. This will be much easier.

```
class async extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{

    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Title");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Your stuff

        publishProgress(progress);//To update the ProgressDialog(Not neccessary)

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pd.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        pd.setMessage(values[0]+"% Completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Thanks! But i am required to use a `ProgressBar` in my case.